# What option should be used to remove extra spaces using astyle?

Tags: c++, formatting, coding-style, code-formatting, astyle

How can I remove extra spaces from my code using `astyle`? For example I want to convert the following code:

```
void foo (     int  a  ,  int   c )
{
d   = a+      c;
}
```

to this:

```
void foo (int a, int c)
{
    d = a + c;
}
```

But astyle is currently converting it to this:

```
void foo (int  a  ,  int   c)
{
    d   = a +      c;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--squeeze-ws can do this job finally (astyle v3.3+)

https://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_squeeze-ws

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to unpad the spaces around operators in astyle.                  If there had been a way to unpad the operators,
you could have first unpadded the spaces, and then again pad them using -p option.

> --pad-oper / -p
>
> Insert space padding around operators.
>
> Any end of line comments will remain in the original column, if possible.
>
> Note that there is no option to unpad. Once padded, they stay padded.

```
if (foo==2)
    a=bar((b-c)*a,d--);
```

> becomes:

```
if (foo == 2)
    a = bar((b - c) * a, d--);
```

Source : http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_pad-oper

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--pad-header / -H` to unpad.

Reference:http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_unpad-paren